# How do I locate an Internet Explorer script error?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, ietester

I'm finishing up my website. Noticed I have some scripting issues in IE7 and IE8.
Using <s>IETester (any better alternative btw?)</s> IE9's debug tools I can test my website for different IE versions.

Updated Example:

[image]

I use JQuery and some 3th party htc files for IE css hacks.
"Line 87" is just a html line so that's not where the error occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IE Developer Tools (built into IE8+) has a JS debugger that will break on errors.

Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open it, select the Script tab, then click the Start Debugging button.

Comment: I was just figuring that out. Still the line numbers don't make any sense + I get "Source code is not available for this location" when I start debugging.

Comment: I took a new screenshot to indicate the issue. This time I pasted the entire jquery JS file in my html file.

Comment: If you look at the 'Call Stack' tab does it give you any clue were the error comes from?

Comment: Ok the Call Stack did help me.

Problem was caused by `behavior: url(border-radius.htc);`

I am now using the much better htc file from http://css3pie.com/